# How can I check to make sure a network connection was successful or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysftp

I am using `pysftp` to connect to a remote sftp server.

The syntax seems simple:

```
with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret') as sftp:

with sftp.cd('/allcode'):
    sftp.put('/pycode/filename')
```

But how can I check to make sure the `pysftp.Connection` was successful and the `sftp.put` actually uploaded the file?  I would like to send an email notification if they are not.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: In the grand tradition of python tutorials everywhere, it looks like the pysftp authors just assume that everything always work. This is a wrapper around paramiko and paramiko will often raise exceptions. You could try different bad things - like wrong host, bad password, no local file, no remote directory and find out what those exceptions are.

Comment: tdelaney hints at the way to do what you want. There is a saying: "It is better to ask for forgiveness than to ask for permission". In this context, it means just send the file over sftp and assume it will work. If it doesn't, the library should throw an exception which you can handle.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ok I think I understand, so put an if statement before?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell No, add an exception handler. An `if` statement is asking for permssion.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice oh wait, you mean to use `paramiko` instead?  thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Not that, either. tdelaney was just mentioning that pysftp uses paramiko under the hood. You probably don't need to use it directly, but getting an understanding of how paramiko deals with error conditions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I check to make sure the pysftp.Connection was successful and the sftp.put actually uploaded the file?

Most likely `pysftp` will throw an exception if there is a problem. You shouldn't check for success before hand. Just send the file and assume it works. Add code to handle exceptions if they occur.

As the saying goes: it is better to ask for forgiveness than to ask for permission.

Comment: Ok thank you, so let it throw the exception?  And then if it does, send an email?  So I just do like `if exception sendEmail()` ? thanks

Comment: I ran the Python script with `dummy` sftp info and got this big exception.  Is this what I need to check for with my `if` statement? ` File "G:\Python\SendFiles.py", line 56, in <module>
    with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret') as sftp:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    self._tconnect['hostkey'] = self._cnopts.get_hostkey(host)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 71, in get_hostkey
    raise SSHException("No hostkey for host %s found." % host)`

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell You have the general right idea, but not the correct syntax. I suggest you read about exception handling in python. Pro tip: don't use an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have any problems with that server then probably it's better to find something else? You may check this [sftp server for windows](https://www.turboftp.com/tbserver/turbo-ftp-server-sftp-server-windows.html) right there in case you are looking for something reliable and trustworthy. I have checked some reviews on the Internet and it looks quite nice. Hood luck with it.